# ¿Como Integrar un Presenter a una Activity vacia?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, mvp

estoy implementando un Presenter a una `Activity` vacia es decir, mi Activity_main esta totalmente vacio sin ningun elemento o widget, me pregunta es: ¿Como integro este Presenter en mi Activity para que me arroje un JSON en ese `Activity` vacio usando un menu:

```
  @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
```

este es mi codigo  **GetDetentionActivity**

```
 public class GetDetentionActivity extends BaseActivity implements GetDetentionPresenter.Callback {


    private GetDetentionPresenter getmGetDetentionPresenter;
    private static final String EXTRA_FIRST = "extraFirst";

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        public static void launch (AppCompatActivity GetDetentionActivity,boolean first){
            Intent intent = new Intent(GetDetentionActivity, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FIRST, first);
            GetDetentionActivity.startActivity(intent);

        }


    }

    @Override
    protected BasePresenter getPresenter() {
        return getmGetDetentionPresenter = new GetDetentionPresenter(this, this) {
            @Override
            protected void implementWS() {

            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccessGetDetention(List<GetDetentionResponse.Motive> detentionList) {

    }

}
```

Mi presentador **GetDetentionPresenter**

```
public  class GetDetentionPresenter extends BaseDemoPresenter implements WSCallback  {

public static String result;
/// Callback
public Callback mCallback;

public interface Callback {
    void onSuccessGetDetention(List<GetDetentionResponse.Motive> detentionList);
}

public GetDetentionPresenter(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity) {
    super(appCompatActivity);
}

@Override
protected void implementWS() {

}

public GetDetentionPresenter(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity, GetDetentionActivity callback) {
    super(appCompatActivity);
    mCallback = callback;
}



public void getDetention() {
    mWSManager.requestWs(GetDetentionResponse.class, WSManager.WS.GET_DETENTION,
            WebServices.services().getDetention(new GetDetentionRequest("1")));
}

private void onSuccessLoadGetDetention(String requestUrl, GetDetentionResponse getDetentionResponse) {
    if (getDetentionResponse.result.equals("0")) {
        mCallback.onSuccessGetDetention(getDetentionResponse.groundsList);
    } else {
        onErrorLoadResponse(requestUrl, getDetentionResponse.resultDescription != null
                ? getDetentionResponse.resultDescription : "");
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestWS(String requestUrl) {
    if (requestUrl.equals(WSManager.WS.GET_DETENTION)) {
        MessageUtils.progress(mAppCompatActivity, "Cargando motivos de detencion...");
    } else {
        MessageUtils.toast(mAppCompatActivity, "Cargando...");
    }
}

@Override
public void onSuccessLoadResponse(String requestUrl, WSBaseResponseInterface baseResponse) {
    MessageUtils.stopProgress();
    if (requestUrl.equals(WSManager.WS.GET_DETENTION)) {
        onSuccessLoadGetDetention(requestUrl, (GetDetentionResponse) baseResponse);
    }
}
@Override
public void onErrorLoadResponse(String requestUrl, String messageError) {
    MessageUtils.stopProgress();
    if (messageError.isEmpty()) {
        MessageUtils.toast(mAppCompatActivity, "Fallo");
    } else {
        MessageUtils.toast(mAppCompatActivity, messageError);
    }
}
@Override
public void onErrorConnection() {
    MessageUtils.toast(mAppCompatActivity, "Sin internet");
}
```

}

Comment: Tu presenter no debería de implementar WSCallback, me imagino que esa es la vista que se encargará de recibir los datos que traiga el presenter, de ser asi...el que se encarga de implementarla es tu activity y en tu presenter sería un tipo variable. Y tu presenter quedaría sin implementar eso, y teniendo una variable de tipo WSCallback, el cual se inicializará en la parte de la activity y será llamado en el presenter cuando se haya ejecutado algo y quiera presentarlo a la vista.

Comment: ¿El json llenaría algún elemento de la activity?

Comment: La Activity solo es un Constraint Layout no tengo nada mas en la Activity, ahi deberian caer los datos del Json

Comment: Algún mensaje en los Toast o el LogCat? @TaniaRiveraGeeky